# Loss is NaN on image classification task

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a basic CNN on the image dataset that contains faces of celebrities with the class assigned corresponding to each person. Given that there are about 10,000 classes I used sparse_categorical_crossentropy rather than one-hot encoding the classes, however as soon as the network starts training the loss is stuck at one number and after several batches is goes to NaN I tried different scaling of the images and a smaller network but with no luck. Any clues on what might be causing the NaN?

Function that generates batches:

```
def Generator(data, label, batch_size):
    url = "../input/celeba-dataset/img_align_celeba/img_align_celeba/"
    INPUT_SHAPE = (109, 109)
    i = 0
    while True:
        image_batch = [ ]
        label_batch = [ ]
        for b in range(batch_size):
            if i == len(data):
                i = 0
                data, label = shuffle(data, label)
            sample = data[i]
            label_batch.append(label[i])
            i += 1
            image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(url + sample), INPUT_SHAPE)
            image_batch.append((image.astype(float)) / 255)

        yield (np.array(image_batch), np.array(label_batch))
```

The model:

```
class CNN():

def __init__(self, train, val, y_train, y_val, batch_size):
    ## Load the batch generator
    self.train_batch_gen = Generator(train, y_train, batch_size)
    self.val_batch_gen = Generator(val, y_val, batch_size)

    self.input_shape = (109, 109, 3)
    self.num_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))
    self.len_train = len(train)
    self.len_val = len(val)

    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.model = self.buildModel()

def buildModel(self):

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=self.input_shape))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same", input_shape=self.input_shape))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(192, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(160, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(320, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"))
    model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))
    model.add(layers.Dense(self.num_classes, activation = "softmax")) #Classification layer or output layer
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

def trainModel(self, epochs):

    self.model.fit_generator(generator=self.train_batch_gen,
                            steps_per_epoch = int(self.len_train // self.batch_size),
                            epochs=epochs,
                            validation_data = self.val_batch_gen,
                            validation_steps = int(self.len_val // self.batch_size))
```

Comment: Did you try varying the learning rate of the Adam optimizer? It could be too small, you should prefer the default values.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I used `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` with labels numbered from `[1,2,3]` (3 classes). In this case it produced NaNs from the start.

When I changed the labels from `[1,2,3]` to `[0,1,2]` the problem has disappeared.

Comment: That's correct especially when the last layer is set to 'softmax' in the multiclassification problems

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are seeing those nans. I suspect it has something to do with your `tanh` activation on your `dense layer`. I would replace it with `relu`. I also suggest **using more neurons on this dense layer** cause 128 is probably small for a 10000 output.

If i were you, i would also try a pre-trained model and/or Siamese networks.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've tried relu and larger dense layer, didn't help, any chance the large number of classes and the small number of images per class can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Exploding Gradients problem. I would recommend you to check how the weights and gradients are varying. See this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2226

Check https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-deal-with-vanishingexploding-gradients-in-keras/ on how to spot exploding gradient problem and solutions to it. Also try out Xavier initialization in your dense layers to prevent exploding gradients.